# Angularjs Unit Test fails for document.getElementById('#elementId') in controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Controller Code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('#elementId');

element.style.display = "block";
```

When a unit test is executed (which executes the above code in controller), it fails with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at
>   ChildScope.$scope.openTab

How to get document/DOM inside the unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating a mocked document element with the help of below code:

```
var mockedDocElement = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('*<<yourElementId>>*').andReturn(mockedDocElement );
```

In this way for every call to **document.getElementById** a dummy element will be returned and thus, you can proceed in your method under test without any such exception.